# Creating a spiral galaxy need math guidance

Tags: c#, math

I am creating a spinning galaxy made of blocks for the stars/systems.

I have been fiddling with this for a few days and have this so far:

```
public int numberArms = 6;
public int numberStars = 1000;
public float galaxyRadius = 500f;
public int spread = 100;

float fHatRandom (float fRange)
{
   float fArea = 4 * Mathf.Atan (6.0f);
   float fP = fArea * Random.value;
   return Mathf.Tan (fP / 4) * fRange / 6.0f;
}

float fLineRandom (float fRange)
{
   float fArea = fRange * fRange / 2;
   float fP = fArea * Random.value;
   return fRange - Mathf.Sqrt (fRange * fRange - 2 * fP);
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
   Random.seed = 100;

   int starsPerArm = numberStars / numberArms;
   float fAngularSpread = spread / numberArms;
   float fArmAngle = (360 / numberArms);
   for (int arm = 0; arm < numberArms; arm++)
   {
     for (int i = 0; i < starsPerArm; i++)
     {
      float fR = fHatRandom (galaxyRadius);      
      float fQ = fLineRandom (fAngularSpread);
      float fK = 1;

      float fA = numberArms * (fArmAngle);

      float fX = fR * Mathf.Cos (Mathf.Deg2Rad * (fA + fR * fK + fQ));
      float fY = fR * Mathf.Sin (Mathf.Deg2Rad * (fA + fR * fK + fQ));

      Vector3 starPos = new Vector3 (fX, fY, arm*4);
      Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere (starPos, 1);

      if (colliders.Length == 0)
      {
          GameObject star = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Cube);
          star.transform.position = starPos;
          star.transform.parent = transform;
      } else
      { 
          i--;//because they overlapped, we try again.
      }
     }    
   }
}
```

}

As it works right now, it creates the spiral arm of the galaxy just fine. But as you can see, I just set the position of the arm to be stacked on the other arms because I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get them to rotate around the center, for that matter my center seems to be off.

I admittedly have the math skills of a gnat and have been fumbling my way through this, can someone help correct the math and get the arms/center where they belong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't that:

```
float fA = numberArms * (fArmAngle);
```

be

```
float fA = arm * (fArmAngle);
```

Just saying...

Comment: geez. like I said, math ability of a gnat. I was changing all the formulas around and trying to figure out why my angle was off...pff.